# Download pdf instead of showing it in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I am using pdfkit on my rails application (I did this according to Ryan Bates [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit))
Currently it's showing the pdf inside the browser.

How can the pdf be downloaded instead ?

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks for the response!

But how can I create the data of the pdf in the controller?

The pdf shows up automatically when the url has `.pdf`. for example when going to this link:

```
http://localhost:3000/home/index.pdf
```

It opens a pdf version of the the page automatically on the browser (it's a rails middleware setup).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the **send_data** method that all rails controllers have.

Something like this:

```
# Generate a PDF document with information on the client and return it.
# The user will get the PDF as a file download.
def download_pdf
  send_data(generate_pdf, :filename => "my_file.pdf", :type => "application/pdf")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it a simple rack end point:

```
class PdfEndpoint
  def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "application/pdf", "Content-Disposition" => "attachment", "filename" => "filename.pdf"}, pdf_data]
  end
end
```

Also the following Railscast will probably help:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware

Answer (score 0):

If the controller action is using [send_data](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data), the option `:disposition` should be equal to **"attachment"** (and not "inline").

For example

```rb
def show
  client = Client.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      send_data(generate_pdf(client), filename: "#{client.name}.pdf", type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'attachement')
    end
  end
end
```

To generate a pdf, you can use [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn).