# Ruby on Rails dynamic file download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to download a pdf file when clicking on a link, but the pdf file will only be generated once the link is clicked.

I have this in my _assignment_sidebar.html.erb file:

```
<ul class="page-action-list">
    <li>
     <a href="#" class="button-sidebar-wide <%= late %>">
       <i class='icon-add'></i> <%= t 'links.submit', "Download Coversheet" %>
     </a>
     <%= link_to new
    </li>
</ul>
```

but I don't know how to link it to my function on the controller.

In assignments_controller.rb I have this:

```
def pdf
    #generate pdf and put into 'private' folder
    send_file Rails.root.join('private', 'output.pdf'), :type=>"application/pdf", :x_sendfile=>true
end
```

which should generate the pdf and send it back to the view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [prawn gem](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) its really simple in essence its should be just like

```
require "prawn"

Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
  text "Hello World!"
end
```

doing another search I just found [wicked_pdf gem](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) its has a really nice documentation but I have not used it like prawn

Comment: Thanks but I know how to generate the pdf. I really need help with downloading it in the html.erb file.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537960/download-pdf-instead-of-showing-it-in-the-browser